# Receiving Error "Daily Limit For Unauthenticated Use Exceeded" When Using Google Calendar API in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm currently working on an application that requires the use of the Google Calendar API in Swift.  Unfortunately, the progress of the project is at a standstill as I'm unable to determine how I need to proceed in order to get past the error shown in the title.  It appears just after performing the google sign in function.  Circumventing the firebase client ID in favor of a different one generated through the Google Developer Console also did not seem to resolve the problem.  On multiple occassions in the code, I added scope values as well as the addition of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile" to the scope based on another stackoverflow user's solution but none of it has resolved my problem.  I do have a Google-Info.plist file who has been properly configured with the reverse ID as well as url scheme, and also attempted to use the client id from that plist file to perform the function, but it still doesn't seem to work.  Below I have included code from the two dominant parts of my program that include references to the calendar api or authorization functions.  Let me know if there's anything you see that may be incorrectly implemented or if I missed a step in getting this to work.  Most of my code is based on the quickstart code provided here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ios?ver=swift

with only slight alterations to allow the additional implementation of Firebase.
Note: Sign-In does appear to work and is successfully communicating data to firebase, it simply isn't allowing further progress once calling Google Calendar.  In adition to what I provided below, there is also a separate viewcontroller that houses the google sign in button, but I don't believe the issues I'm having reside in that class, hence its exclusion.

```
APPDELEGATE
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn
import FirebaseDatabase
import GoogleAPIClientForREST

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

    var scopes = [kGTLRAuthScopeCalendarReadonly, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"]


    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes = scopes


        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }


    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

        if let err = error {
            print("Failed to log into Google: ", err)

            return
        }

        print("Successfully logged into Google", user)
        //Allows information to be stored in Firebase Database
        let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://tesseractscheduler.firebaseio.com/")

        guard let idToken = user.authentication.idToken else { return }
        guard let accessToken = user.authentication.accessToken else { return }
        LoginController().service.authorizer = user.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()
        let credentials = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken, accessToken: accessToken)

        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credentials, completion: { (user, error) in
            if let err = error {
            print("Failed to create a Firebase User with Google account: ", err)
                return

            }

            //successfully authenticated user
            guard let uid = user?.uid else { return }
            print("Successfully logged into Firebase with Google", uid)



            //Creates database entry with users unique identifier, username, and email.  "null" provided to prevent errors.
            ref.updateChildValues(["UID": uid, "username": user?.displayName ?? "null", "Email": user?.email ?? "null"])

            //Pushes to next screen if login has occurred.
            if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain(){
                //GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "197204473417-56pqo0dhn8v2nf5v64aj7o64ui414rv7.apps.googleusercontent.com"
                self.window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: LoginController())
            }
            LoginController().fetchEvents()
        })

    }




    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options:
        [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {




        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                          sourceApplication: options[

                        UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String!, annotation : options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])

        return true
    }

LOGINCONTROLLER
import UIKit
import GoogleSignIn
import Firebase
import GoogleAPIClientForREST

class LoginController: UIViewController {


    let service = GTLRCalendarService()
    let output = UITextView()
    let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(didTapSignOut))
         view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 61/255, green: 91/255, blue: 151/255, alpha: 1)

        output.frame = view.bounds
        output.isEditable = false
        output.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 20, right: 0)
        output.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        output.isHidden = true
        view.addSubview(output);



        }

    func fetchEvents() {
        let query = GTLRCalendarQuery_EventsList.query(withCalendarId: "primary")
        query.maxResults = 10
        query.timeMin = GTLRDateTime(date: Date())
        query.singleEvents = true
        query.orderBy = kGTLRCalendarOrderByStartTime
        service.executeQuery(
            query,
            delegate: self,
            didFinish: #selector(displayResultWithTicket(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:)))
    }

    @objc func displayResultWithTicket(
        ticket: GTLRServiceTicket,
        finishedWithObject response : GTLRCalendar_Events,
        error : NSError?) {

        if let error = error {
            showAlert(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        var outputText = ""
        if let events = response.items, !events.isEmpty {
            for event in events {
                let start = event.start!.dateTime ?? event.start!.date!
                let startString = DateFormatter.localizedString(
                    from: start.date,
                    dateStyle: .short,
                    timeStyle: .short)
                outputText += "\(startString) - \(event.summary!)\n"
            }
        } else {
            outputText = "No upcoming events found."
        }
        output.text = outputText
    }

    private func presentViewController(alert: UIAlertController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) -> Void {
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: flag, completion: completion)
    }
    //Shows an error alert with a specified output from the log.
    func showAlert(title : String, message: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(
            title: title,
            message: message,
            preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert
        )
        let ok = UIAlertAction(
            title: "OK",
            style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,
            handler: nil
        )
        alert.addAction(ok)
        presentViewController(alert: alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    //Communicated to navigation button to perform logout function.
    @objc func didTapSignOut(_ sender: AnyObject) {
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
            print("Successfully logged out of Google.")
            showAlert(title: "Log Off", message: "Logout Successful!")
        appDelegate?.window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())

    }




        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

Please let me know if there's anything else you would need provided to be able to help identify the issue.  I've searched quite extensively and been unable to find a solution for my particular issue.  I apologize if it's a silly question: I'm still fairly new to the incorporation of APIs.

Comment: Why are you signing in with Firebase Auth in order to use Google Calender API?

Comment: There is probably a better way of doing it, but using this method may make it easier to pull user information for a third api I'll be implementing once I get calendar to work.  Still not 100% sure if it'll be necessary, but that's as far as I've gotten with it.  At present, the information Firebase is pulling is purely for testing purposes and will likely not be pulled or required by the time the code is finalized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say for sure if there is a more effective workaround yet, but for now I have been able to avoid this error by stripping the code of all references to Firebase and ignoring its implementation.  Something about the way I was authenticating Google Sign In with Firebase was causing this error to occur.  It is no longer an issue after Firebase's removal.  El Tomato's question led me to trying this method and so far I have at least been able to progress.  If I have time later in the project, I may come back to see if it's possible to implement them both without the error occurring, but for now it's a non-vital feature.